# Tablet Kiosk - Sense when a user has stepped away

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ipad, motion-detection

We are developing a web/cordova application that will sit on a Kiosk. The tablet should sense when the user (employee) has stepped away, actions will be taken when the user has left. Our security team is not thrilled about only using timeouts.

So now we are looking into Motion Detector and weight/pad sensor.

Has anyone implemented a system like this and what sensors or other approach do you recommend.

Edit: Changed Proximity Sensor to Motion Detector

Comment: Proximity sensors on Android devices were designed to detect if a phone is close to someone's face, so they most likely won't have the range to detect this.  I think motion detection is usually done through a camera (which can be the front camera of the tablet), but that may be a more of a development effort than you want. There's nothing inthe Android API to help. Somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876516/proximity-sensor-accuracy

Comment: Motion Detector was the term I was looking for not Proximity Sensor, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: This is interesting. What if the employee steps away and someone who is not an employee steps closer to the device, how will you tell the difference?

Comment: That is a valid point that we are aware of however, we have decided that we are not as much concerned of someone with malicious intent as we are someone walking up to the kiosk and accidentally seeing other employees information. There is definitely a certain level of sensitivity that should be taken into account either way.

Comment: Our product KioWare Kiosk Software (full disclosure: I work there) supports both the Android motion sensor and the [Larco pressure mat/Larco SonicGuard devices](http://larco.com/presence-sensing) for doing presence detection. The devices send keystroke combinations that are configurable (via a Windows app) [for a Walk-away and a Walk-To sequence](http://www.kioware.com/devices/larco/usb_security_mat_-_keyboard). You could easily add something similar to what we do with the device, where you go into a session end mode when you see the device signal that someone left, via the keystroke sequence.